# Why don't captchas work in UBUNTU Browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

When I post an answer then I get a google capcha nag screen.
I can copy and paste the code but there is no submit button.

Please get rid of these capchas I'm not a robot!!!!

Comment: This happens when using 3g connection, it's just weird that on a Ubuntu website the website complains that Ubuntu's own browser is not supported after presenting a captcha to me. 3g is indeed a bit slow but the whole captcha and unsupported browser stuff thats just silly...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are being routed through VPN, or Tor.  If it senses a weird connection, it asks for captchas.  Try checking your ip address by doing a speedtest.

Comment: Is that a reason to refuse a human to have some privacy? Yes, there are privacy measures on it's connection. But no, non of the users are robot's.